# print in last row the literal "execute;" - number of rows always different

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

This is my SQL code to generate a batch file

```
SELECT    'CANCEL_TRANS trans WITH serial = "'
   || serial
   || '" , short_name = "'
   || short_name
   || '";'
FROM trans
WHERE ( (trans.status = 0))
   AND TO_TIMESTAMP (time_created, 'YYYY/MM/DD-HH24:MI:SS.FF') <
          SYSDATE - 1 / 24
   AND platform_name LIKE '%test%';
```

output

(always differnet number of rows)

```
CANCEL_TRANS trans WITH serial = "507760" , short_name = "BD";
CANCEL_TRANS trans WITH serial = "507761" , short_name = "BD";
CANCEL_TRANS trans WITH serial = "507781" , short_name = "BD";
CANCEL_TRANS trans WITH serial = "507782" , short_name = "BD";
CANCEL_TRANS trans WITH serial = "507785" , short_name = "BD";
CANCEL_TRANS trans WITH serial = "507786" , short_name = "BD";
CANCEL_TRANS trans WITH serial = "507880" , short_name = "BD";
CANCEL_TRANS trans WITH serial = "507883" , short_name = "BD";
CANCEL_TRANS trans WITH serial = "507884" , short_name = "BD";
CANCEL_TRANS trans WITH serial = "507886" , short_name = "BD";
CANCEL_TRANS trans WITH serial = "507976" , short_name = "BD";
CANCEL_TRANS trans WITH serial = "507964" , short_name = "BD";
CANCEL_TRANS trans WITH serial = "507967" , short_name = "BD";
CANCEL_TRANS trans WITH serial = "507971" , short_name = "BD";
CANCEL_TRANS trans WITH serial = "507762" , short_name = "BD";
CANCEL_TRANS trans WITH serial = "508096" , short_name = "BD";
```

I wish to print in last row this string/literal. Wish to do that with SQL (not shell script):

```
execute;
```

Comment: add at the end this: union select 'execute;' from dual

Comment: thank you. That was it. Quite simpel.

Answer (score 2):

Use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT ...
UNION ALL
SELECT 'execute;' from dual
```

Comment: UNION may sort the rows because it acts as a DISTINCT. Much safer to use UNION ALL or an ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

You use this code:

```
SELECT top 1 'CANCEL_TRANS trans WITH serial = "' || serial 
              || '" , short_name = "' || short_name || '";' 
  FROM trans 
 WHERE trans.status = 0
   AND TO_TIMESTAMP(time_created, 'YYYY/MM/DD-HH24:MI:SS.FF') < SYSDATE - 1 / 24 
   AND platform_name LIKE '%test%' order by serial desc;
```

Comment: 1. TOP is not an Oracle instruction. 2. Please use the formatting tools (it's your first answer, you can use the edit link to correct your answer).